# scraping data from website which uses Ajax requests

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm have made a program for scraping data from a website
so far I have made a program using python and selenium and beautifulsoup and when it wants to scrape data from a page of that website like [this one](http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=9211775239375291)
I have to click on a tab named "سابقه" (at the top and it's in torquoise color)then website uses Ajax request to get the data and after that I loop through the table and the table has more than one page so I have to click on numbers below the table and collect new data again.
My problem is this method is really slow because I also have to collect data from 500 pages and every page contains 35 tables.
Is there any other faster way to do this?Or maybe a way to fire Ajax request within my program and get the response.It would be better if the solution be in python.

Comment: `AJAX request` is normal request executed by JavaScript - so if you know its url, its method (POST,GET) and its parameters (headers, cookies, etc.) then you can do this request manually using `requests` or `urllib` to make it faster then `Selenium`. You can use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests in tab `Network` in `DevTool`.

Comment: BTW: mostly `AJAX` sends data as `JSON` which you can easily convert to python dictionary using module `json` but sometimes it can send data encrypted and then there is the problem to decrypt it (if you don't know how data were encrypted).

Comment: You are right first I tried that the method for onclick event of those buttons is showtab(number) but I could'nt find this method using the chorme devtools search where do I have to look for it

Comment: you could raise multiple instances of the browser and Beautiful Soup to extract the data from the different sites simultaneously

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: in `DevTool` I use tab `Network` and select `XHR` to see only javascript requests. And I see url `http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=9211775239375291&Top=999999&A=0` and it sends data like `20171213@901.00@863.00@893.00@901.00@901.00@859.00@411324010096.00@460750068@...` and there are values `901.00`, `863.00`, etc. which I see in table on the page.

Comment: you could catch this url many times to compare values in `i‌​=9211775239375291&To‌​p=999999&A=0` - maybe they never change, but maybe `i` is `timestamp` and you have to change it to get current data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab uses JavaScript to get all data from url

http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=9211775239375291&Top=999999&A=0

and later only change data in table. Other tabs use different urls but rest should be similar.

You can use `requests` to get all at once

```
import requests

url = 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=9211775239375291&Top=999999&A=0'

r = requests.get(url)

print(r.text[:50]) # first 50 chars

data = r.text.split(';')

print('number od days:', len(data))

for row in data: # data[:5]: # first 5 rows
    row = row.split('@')
    print('date:', row[0], '|', row[1:4]) # first 3 values
```

Result (small preview)

```
20171213@901.00@863.00@893.00@901.00@901.00@859.00

number od days: 1202

date: 20171213 | ['901.00', '863.00', '893.00']
date: 20171212 | ['859.00', '859.00', '859.00']
date: 20171211 | ['823.00', '782.00', '819.00']
date: 20171210 | ['796.00', '780.00', '784.00']
date: 20171209 | ['797.00', '781.00', '787.00']
...
```

---

BTW: you could do it also with standard module `urllib.request` but server sends data compressed with `gzip` so you would have to use module `gzipFile` to manually uncompress it.

Or you could try to send request with header `Accept-Encoding: deflate` to inform server that you need data uncompressed.

---

I don't know if `url` always has the same values in arguments

```
i=9211775239375291&Top=999999&A=0
```

but value `i` is also in page url

http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=9211775239375291